# PhoneGap 2.5.0, how to open external URL for iPad/iPhone?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I try to open external url like this,

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_system" >
```

and also try with `_blank` but it's open in same app screen not open in safari browser,

How to resolve..?

Answer (score 13):

If you change your links to use the new InAppBrowser syntax, then it's easy to open your URLs either in the system web browser, the InAppBrowser or the actual webview of your app.

This code should open your URL in the system web browser (Safari on iOS):

```
<a href="#" onclick="var ref = window.open('http://google.com', '_system');">
```

Changing `'_system'` to `'_blank'` will open the URL in the InAppBrowser.

Changing `'_system'` to `'_self'` will open the URL in the webview of your app (if the domain is whitelisted) or the InAppBrowser (if the domain is not whitelisted).

Sample Gist: https://gist.github.com/wicketyjarjar/7043336

*Note: Cordova/PhoneGap 3.0+ require the InAppBrowser plugin to be installed before this will work.*

To install the InAppBrowser plugin (if necessary)...

Using Cordova: `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser`

Using PhoneGap: `phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser`

Comment: I try to this one also but not working link open in same AppBrowser

Comment: It is not working for me. For all options page is opening in app

Comment: If you're using Cordova/PhoneGap 3.0+ you now need to add the InAppBrowser plugin separately through the command line before it will work.  Just updated my answer above with more info and an updated Gist.  Also, here's my answer to a similar question that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19453481/2103983

Answer (score 0):

My solution is like below:
first I define a function to open safary url:

```
LaunchNewWindow: function (url) {       
   if (window.location.toStringing().match(/file/i) && navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i) ) {   
    window.open(url+"_xex_", "_blank");}
   else{
    window.open(url, "_blank");
   }
}
```

then you have to change code in CordovaLic\Classses\CDViewController.m (CordovalLib 3.0.0)  to handle your spacial url:
I added it in line685 :

```
    else {

// start stoneskin's change: force open external url in safari                              
                              if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
    NSString *myurlstr = [url absoluteString];
    if ([myurlstr rangeOfString:@"_xex_"].location != NSNotFound){
        myurlstr = [myurlstr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_xex_" withString:@""];
        NSURL *myurl = [NSURL URLWithString:myurlstr];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myurl];
        return NO;
    }

}
//end start stoneskin's change
if ([self.whitelist schemeIsAllowed:[url scheme]]) {
    return [self.whitelist URLIsAllowed:url];
} else {
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
} else { // handle any custom schemes to plugins
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification object:url]];
}
}

return NO;
}
```